# How can I enable the scrolling in a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I was building a view and then I realized that I needed to put too much information inside, so it would not fit in the window. So I decided to create a JScrollPane to put all the elements inside, and continue including new elements if needed, be able to see it all in my window.

This is the code for my scroll pane:

```
public JPanel getActionsPane() {
    if (Objects.isNull(actionsPane)){
        actionsPane = new JPanel();
        actionsPane.setLayout(null);
        actionsPane.setBounds(0, 29, 1580, 1450);
        addComponents();
    }
    return actionsPane;
}

public JScrollPane getActionsScrollPane() {
    if (Objects.isNull(actionsScrollPane)){
        actionsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        actionsScrollPane.add(getActionsPane());
        actionsScrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        actionsScrollPane.setBounds(0, 29, 593, 400);
        actionsScrollPane.setViewportView(getActionsPane());
    }
    return actionsScrollPane;
}
```

But when I compile, I can only see this:

[[image: JScrollPane in runtime]]

As you can see, the scroll is not being showed. I have not worked very much with JScrollPane in the past, maybe I am missing some propierty to enable the scrolls?

Comment: The default is scroll panes become visible when needed.  Your image shows that they're not needed with the amount of data you're displaying.  Also, use Swing layout managers.  Don't set bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/users/300257/gilbert-le-blanc, I added a new image that shows the scrolls are not working properly, because there is more information, below, so scroll should appear automatically. I will follow your advice to use layout managers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I follow several advices, tried to use layouts, none of this worked for me. Finally, thanks to a friends suggestion, I manage to do it, without layouts, just modifying my old approach.

```
public UI_ReembolsoFondoRegistrar(Window window) {
    super(window);
    setBounds(100, 100, 593, 750);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Reembolsar el fondo para dietas y pagos menores");
    buttonPane.add(getBtnAceptar());
    buttonPane.add(getBtnCancelar());
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);
    contentPanel.add(getLblFecha());

    contentPanel.add(getActionsScrollPane());

    contentPanel.add(getLblCustodio());
    contentPanel.add(getCbxCustodio());
    contentPanel.add(getLblContab());
    contentPanel.add(getCbxContab());
    contentPanel.add(getLblRevisado());
    contentPanel.add(getCbxRevisado());
    contentPanel.add(getLblAprobado());
    contentPanel.add(getCbxAprobado());
    contentPanel.add(getLblCheque());
    contentPanel.add(getTxtCheque());
    contentPanel.add(getLblFecha_1());
    contentPanel.add(getDateChooser());
    contentPanel.add(getLblAnotado());
    contentPanel.add(getCbxAnotado());
    contentPanel.add(getSeparator_2());
}

public JPanel getActionsPane() {
    if (Objects.isNull(actionsPane)){
        actionsPane = new JPanel();
        actionsPane.setLayout(null);
        actionsPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1580,525));
        addComponents();
    }
    return actionsPane;
}

public JScrollPane getActionsScrollPane() {
    if (Objects.isNull(actionsScrollPane)){
        actionsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(getActionsPane(), JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        actionsScrollPane.setViewportView(getActionsPane());
        actionsScrollPane.setBounds(0,28,593,480);
    }
    return actionsScrollPane;
}

private void addComponents(){
    actionsPane.add(getPanelGastosViaje());
    actionsPane.add(getPanelValePM());
    actionsPane.add(getLblCuenta());
    actionsPane.add(getCbxCuenta());
    actionsPane.add(getLblOCC());
    actionsPane.add(getCbxOCC());
    actionsPane.add(getLblCUP());
    actionsPane.add(getTxtCUP());
    actionsPane.add(getTxtTotalCUP());
    actionsPane.add(getBtnDesCUP());
    actionsPane.add(getSeparator_1());
    actionsPane.add(getLblCUC());
    actionsPane.add(getTxtCUC());
    actionsPane.add(getTxtTotalCUC());
    actionsPane.add(getBtnDesCUC());
    actionsPane.add(getContrapartidasTableJP());
}
```

[image: Scroll working now]